# Why do I need a server to develop a phonegap app

Tags: cordova

I'm new to phone gap development, but the documentation says the following:

Specifying a Server URL

The prepackaged PhoneGap files shipped with Profound UI include a file named app.js, which serves as the main configuration file for your Profound UI application.  The first step is to point app.js to your server.  At the top of the file, find the following line:
pui.serverURL ="http://your_ibmi_server";

What's a ibmi server and why do I need one?

Comment: i think its not compulsory. you can build your offline application. using any UI plugin+phonegap

Comment: What's "Profound UI"? You don't need a server for plain PhoneGap.

Answer (score 0):

The phonegap documentation on the official site had some tweaks when I visited and thus had to take help from other resources . But it definitely tells you the basic things very well .
Here is how phonegap works , phonegap creates workspace for you so that you can port your HTML5 app to other platform , for that you'll need to create a workspace using shell commands (command prompt ) and then connect it to the IDE (like ecllipse ) , there a js library provided cordova.js that will give you functions to interact with the device(like android phone) you're working on like the accessing the camera etc . 
Thus no server side work till you need it ,you can always use js to send data to your server and do what you want from it but that is only an option .
Hope this helps.